# Load links inside container (Bootstrap Stater-Template)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load links/urls in a container field using Bootstrap Starter Template found at the following link: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

The following source code of the above page is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

        <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

       <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
       <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

       <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
       <![endif]-->
    </head>



 <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="starter-template">
                <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
                <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My final goal is to load the links i.e. options from the navbar/menu bar inside the container. As of now, adding a url to 
    "

About

" 
opens the link in a new webpage without my navbar. Instead I would like to open the link in the the following location:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

This would ensure that the navbar would be present while I navigate through the pages.

Please let me know if you need any confirmation. The following link can be used to see the website:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

Comment: You don't need to add the whole html. Just add the specific portion where you need help.

Comment: Yea sorry for that. To sum things up, when I click something from the menu option, I want the result url (set as href="something") to be displayed in the above container.

Answer (score 0):

There are global sections on each page, such as the logo, navbar, footer, and so forth. The .container  and it's columns may or may not change per page. If you just want to change the text inside the .container you would make a page called about.html, link to it from all instances in your menu, and copy over the entire page. You can use includes, use a CMS, or copy the entire html and then changing the html inside the section you want. To load content inside a certain div from another source you can use jQuery or javascript or an iframe, but that is not the way to do create a site normally. You can look up iframes and loading html inside a div, there's help all over for that, but normal sites are not built that way.